# Does calling storcli on a hard disk drive induce read/write latency?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, smartctl, storcli

I am calling

> storcli /c0/eall/sall show all

on some 4TB Western Digital hard disk drives to get their SMART code status. When I do this it causes significant write latency to the disks, is that normal? Is there a way to get the SMART status of the hard disk drives without inducing the latency?